# Labeling individual bars in barplots to 3 significant figures using the functions sprintf() in ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart

**Overview:**

I have a summarised dataframe called **"leaf.aggregate.1 (see below)"** and I want to label the values **(i.e. to 3 significant figures)** for Mean_Canopy_Index per Urbanisation_index category **(x-axis)** onto the bars in the barplot using **ggplot()**.

As you can see **(barplot below - not using the sprintf() function)**,the bars entitled 1, 3 and 4 for the Urbanisation_index are labelled to 7 decimal places (e.g. 61.66667, 76.42857, and 72.05882).

How do you show the Mean_Canopy_Index values on the individual bars to **3 significant figures** (i.e. 61.7, 75.0, 76.4, and 72.1) instead?

From browsing different answers on **Stackoverflow**, I tried to incorporate [these](https://structure(list(Species%20=%20structure(c(1L,%201L,%201L,%201L),%20.Label%20=%20%22Quercus%20petraea%22,%20class%20=%20%22factor%22),%20%20%20%20%20%20Urbanisation_Index%20=%20c(1,%202,%203,%204),%20Counts%20=%20c(6,%2017,%2014,%20%20%20%20%20%2017),%20Mean_Canopy_Index%20=%20c(61.6666666666667,%2075,%2076.4285714285714,%20%20%20%20%20%2072.0588235294118),%20SD_Canopy_Index%20=%20c(17.5119007154183,%20%20%20%20%20%2020,%2010.2710518202619,%2016.494205756247)),%20class%20=%20%22data.frame%22,%20row.names%20=%20c(NA,%20%20-4L))) suggestions, but I was unsuccessful.

The solution suggests the function **sprintf()** is the most appropriate method; however, the Mean_Canopy_Index column is numeric, not a character (see the error message for 'Attempt 2' in R-code section).

If anyone can help, I would be deeply appreciative.

**R-code**

```
#Attempt 1

Canopy_barplot<-ggplot(data=leaf.aggregate.1, aes(x=Urbanisation_Index, y=Mean_Canopy_Index)) +
                                                      geom_bar(stat="identity", color="steelblue", fill="steelblue", width=0.5) +
                                                      geom_text(aes(label=Mean_Canopy_Index), vjust=1.6, color="white", size=3.5, round(aes(label=Mean_Canopy_Index, digits = 2)))+
                                                      theme_minimal() +
                                                      theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
                                                      panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
                                                      panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

#Error message
Error in round(aes(label = Mean_Canopy_Index, digits = 2)) : 
 non-numeric argument to mathematical function

#Attempt 2


                  Canopy_barplot<-ggplot(data=leaf.aggregate.1, aes(x=Urbanisation_Index, y=Mean_Canopy_Index)) +
                                         geom_bar(stat="identity", color="steelblue", fill="steelblue", width=0.5) +
                                         geom_text(aes(label=Mean_Canopy_Index), vjust=1.6, color="white", size=3.5)+
                                         sprintf(aes(label=Mean_Canopy_Index("%0.2f", round(Mean_Canopy_Index, digits = 2))))+
                                         theme_minimal() +
                                         theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
                                         panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
                                         panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

#Error message
    Error in sprintf(aes(label = Mean_Canopy_Index("%0.2f", round(Mean_Canopy_Index,  : 
  'fmt' is not a character vector
```

**Barplot without using the function sprintf()**

```
#R-code

Canopy_barplot<-ggplot(data=leaf.aggregate.1, aes(x=Urbanisation_Index, y=Mean_Canopy_Index)) +
                                             geom_bar(stat="identity", color="steelblue", fill="steelblue", width=0.5) +
                                             geom_text(aes(label=Mean_Canopy_Index), vjust=1.6, color="white", size=3.5)+
                                             theme_minimal() +
                                             theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
                                             panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
                                             panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

**Data Structure**

```
str(leaf.aggregate.1)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Species           : Factor w/ 1 level "Quercus petraea": 1 1 1 1
 $ Urbanisation_Index: num  1 2 3 4
 $ Counts            : num  6 17 14 17
 $ Mean_Canopy_Index : num  61.7 75 76.4 72.1
 $ SD_Canopy_Index   : num  17.5 20 10.3 16.5
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Quercus petraea", class = "factor"), 
    Urbanisation_Index = c(1, 2, 3, 4), Counts = c(6, 17, 14, 
    17), Mean_Canopy_Index = c(61.6666666666667, 75, 76.4285714285714, 
    72.0588235294118), SD_Canopy_Index = c(17.5119007154183, 
    20, 10.2710518202619, 16.494205756247)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: According to linked answer `format(round(Mean_Canopy_Index, 1))` should work

Comment: Just using `aes(label= round(Mean_Canopy_Index, digits = 2))` didn't work?

Comment: @Jaap OP wants `75.0` too

Comment: @PoGibas ok, then this can be closed indeed

Comment: In this instance, my question relates to changing values to significant figures on individual bar plots using ggplot() notation. Although, I can run the suggested code in the possible duplicate solution above, it’s not really a duplicate question. I am unsure how to incorporate the suggested code into geom_text() in ggplot() format. If anyone can help, then many thanks.

Comment: Doesn't `aes(label = format(round(Mean_Canopy_Index, 1)))` work for you?

Comment: I disagree, this question should not be closed. Beginners and /intermediate R users (like me) will find this type of question really useful. I successfully figured out how to change numerical values into 1, 2, or 3 decimal places separately, but I was unable to integrate these solutions into the correct geom_text() format due to on my current knowledge base. There are people (like me) who frequently use 'Stackoverflow' as a source of help but are not as advanced yet! It takes practice and continued learning from kind people like yourselves who are willing to help, and pass on your knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, `sprintf("%.1f", ...)` will give you 3 sig. fig. (1 decimal precision):

```
    df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Urbanisation_Index, y=Mean_Canopy_Index)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="steelblue", fill="steelblue", width=0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%.1f", Mean_Canopy_Index)),
            vjust=1.6,
            color="white",
            size=3.5)+
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Comment: Doesn't work as OP wants `75.0`

Comment: Thanks, Paul! Thank you so much! I was trying to get my code right for a long time using different combinations of code. Your right, I was so close. Still learning! Take care and have a good day